# Tab-delimited values to YAML conversion

Tags: text-processing, awk, yaml

I have a file with tab-delimited values in this format:

```
your-email  your-order-id   PayPal-transaction-id   your-first-name your-second-name
s@ess.com   12345   54321   sooky   spooky
t@tee.com   23456   23456   kiki    dee
r@arrgh.com 34567   76543   cheeky  chappy
```

and I'd like to use `awk` to convert this to YAML:

```yaml
---

your-email: s@ess.com
your-order-id: 12345
PayPal-transaction-id: 54321
your-first-name: sooky
your-second-name: spooky

your-email: t@tee.com
your-order-id: 23456
PayPal-transaction-id: 23456
your-first-name: kiki
your-second-name: dee

your-email: r@arrgh.com
your-order-id: 34567
PayPal-transaction-id: 76543
your-first-name: cheeky
your-second-name: chappy
```

So far, my awk script looks like this:

```c
#!/usr/bin/awk
FS=="\t"
BEGIN {print "---"} 
NR==1 {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i ": "}
```

But I can't figure out how to get each field from line 1 onwards to print after its header and recreate the YAML key values from the first line of the input file. In the real file, there are 38 fields and 34 records (so not huge).

Comment: Note that the YAML document you depict is probably not what you actually want: you repeatedly overwrite the value of the 5 keys, so you would get only the info for the last order when you loaded the document. You probably want either a series of subdocuments -- in which case you should change the blank lines to `---` -- or you want a list of dictionaries (that would be my preferred choice.), in which case you should prefix the `your-email` lines with `- ` and indent the other non-blank ones two spaces. See the [YAML reference-card](http://www.yaml.org/refcard.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
$ cat inf
your-email  your-order-id   PayPal-transaction-id   your-first-name your-second-name
s@ess.com   12345   54321   sooky   spooky
t@tee.com   23456   23456   kiki    dee
r@arrgh.com 34567   76543   cheeky  chappy
$ cat mkf.sh
awk '
BEGIN {
  print "---\n"
}
NR == 1 {
  nc = NF
  for(c = 1; c <= NF; c++) {
    h[c] = $c
  }
}
NR > 1 {
  for(c = 1; c <= nc; c++) {
    printf h[c] ": " $c "\n"
  }
  print ""
}' inf
$ ./mkf.sh inf
---

your-email: s@ess.com
your-order-id: 12345
PayPal-transaction-id: 54321
your-first-name: sooky
your-second-name: spooky

your-email: t@tee.com
your-order-id: 23456
PayPal-transaction-id: 23456
your-first-name: kiki
your-second-name: dee

your-email: r@arrgh.com
your-order-id: 34567
PayPal-transaction-id: 76543
your-first-name: cheeky
your-second-name: chappy
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks. I would upvote but my poor reputation precludes that :-(

Comment: @duff No worries, glad it worked as expected for you!

Comment: @duff Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer marks the issue as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to define an iterable integer variable set to zero in begin and run an if/else statement that if "iter==0" saves the field names to elements in an array then autoincrements the integer or else it does the record print you've written (except printing out the fields by using your `i` iterable? ([more information on awk arrays](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_83.html#SEC86)).

I haven't tested this code at all (and I suck something awful at `awk` in general), but it should serve as a concrete illustration of the general programming/scripting concept:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
FS=="\t"
BEGIN {
   print "---"
   iter=0
} 
NR==1 
{

   if (iter == 0)
      for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
         newArr[i]=$i
      iter++
   else
      for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
         print newArr[i] ": " $i

}
```

Comment: I get a syntax error when trying to run this:`gawk: ./a.awk:15: else` the arrow (`^`) indicates the `e` of else. could you explain the `NR==1`? Won't that make your code execute _only_ on the first line?

Comment: Yeah, like I said, it was just an illustration, not final code. I looks like @icyrock.com has essentially re-created the same basic script except using `NR` instead of an if/else statement. I would try to use their code.

Comment: OK, fair enough, I thought it was some dark trickery I was not aware of :). Sorry, next time I'll read the text of your answer as well as the code.

Comment: I didn't mean to catch the `NR`, that's from your code that you provided, I just worked off that as a template. Near as I can tell from the other person's code, it matches line numbers so I'm assuming `NR` is "number of record" and the statement before the curly brace is a conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this can be done in `awk` but if a Perl answer is acceptable, this should do what you need:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
print "---\n";
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    ## This splits the line at one or more whitespace characters
    ## into the array @fields.
    @fields=split(/\t+/);
    ## Get the column names if this is the 1st line
    if ($.==1){@cols=@fields}
    ## Print the data if it is not the first line
    else {
      print "\n";
      for ($i=0;$i<=$#fields;$i++){
        print "$cols[$i] : $fields[$i]\n";
      }
    }
}
```

For example:

```
$./foo.pl input_text.txt
---

your-email: s@ess.com
your-order-id: 12345
PayPal-transaction-id: 54321
your-first-name: sooky
your-second-name: spooky

your-email: t@tee.com
your-order-id: 23456
PayPal-transaction-id: 23456
your-first-name: kiki
your-second-name: dee

your-email: r@arrgh.com
your-order-id: 34567
PayPal-transaction-id: 76543
your-first-name: cheeky
your-second-name: chappy
```

This can be condensed into a one-liner using Perl's `-a` option which splits each line into the array `@F`:

```
echo "---";perl  -aF"\t" -ne 'if ($.==1){@c=@F; chomp($c[$#c]);}else {
 print "\n";for ($i=0;$i<=$#F;$i++){print "$c[$i]: $F[$i]\n";}}' input_text.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
csvjson -t file | yq -y .
```

Assuming the fields of the original data are delimited by tabs, this uses `csvjson` (from [the `csvkit` toolkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) to convert the data to JSON format.  The `yq` parser (from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) is then used to transcode the JSON into YAML.

Given the data in the question, the final output will be the YAML document

```yaml
- your-email: s@ess.com
  your-order-id: 12345
  PayPal-transaction-id: 54321
  your-first-name: sooky
  your-second-name: spooky
- your-email: t@tee.com
  your-order-id: 23456
  PayPal-transaction-id: 23456
  your-first-name: kiki
  your-second-name: dee
- your-email: r@arrgh.com
  your-order-id: 34567
  PayPal-transaction-id: 76543
  your-first-name: cheeky
  your-second-name: chappy
```

I'm noting that the expected output in the question makes little sense as it's a single section with multiple duplicated keys (a key's value is overwritten by a later instance of that same key).  I've therefore chosen to ignore that in favour of a document without duplicated keys (the above document contains a list of three objects).

In place of `csvjson -j file` you may instead use

```bash
mlr --itsv --ojson --jlistwrap cat file
```

... which uses Miller (`mlr`) from https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ to convert the tab-delimited input into JSON.

In place of `yq -y .` you may use

```bash
yj -jy
```

... which uses `yj` from https://github.com/sclevine/yj to translate JSON to YAML.

Any combination of the four tools mentioned for TSV-->JSON and JSON-->YAML transcoding will give you the same (or equivalent) result in the end.